# Syntax highlighting-less IDE?

Tags: windows, ide

Is there a Syntax highlighting-less IDE windows compatible that I can use? Currently how my IDE looks:

[image: IDE]

Comment: Notepad + powershell can be used, notepad to write code, powershell to compile and run code. I prefer using an IDE though, since you can then think of things like program logic, and less about syntax and formatting.

Comment: @Irsu85 You do have a point I guess... Maybe I'll stick with my current IDE (VS Code)

Comment: You can create a theme for coloring and give to all elements the same colour (it will work with any IDE)

Comment: Thanks for the help @flavio, but I'll stick with my current look :)

Comment: I don't get it. How shall it look like instead? Just black and white? Can you use Photoshop and draw a picture of how you want it to be?

Comment: Haha... I'm not good at photoshop only illustrator but ummn not exactly black and white I only don't want syntax highlighting but it can be colourful like vs code and it must have integrate-able extensions unlike notepad  but essentially yeah the text must be just one colour

Comment: It is currently very unclear what you are looking for. You write you want a "Syntax highlighting-less", which I guess to many people means you want to remove the colouring of the text. On the other hand, on a suggestion that achieves exactly this, you reply "I'll stick with my current look" (i.e. with the colours). Then, you add "not exactly black and white I only don't want syntax highlighting", which sounds quite oxymoronic. Therefore, please describe and possibly sketch what you actually want your IDE to look like.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable syntax highlighting in VS Code itself, by any one of these methods:

1. Add the following code to `settings.json`

> ```
> "files.associations": {
>     "*.*": "plaintext",
> },
> ```

2. Download the Plain Theme extension from the marketplace.
   [image: Picture of the extension]